# Get current NSDate with a format of: dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get the current date with the following format: `dd/MM/yyyy`.

The way I would format it, is like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
```

And I would get the current date like this: `[NSDate date]`. How can I mix the 2 together, and get the current date with that format?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `NSDateFormat`? Have you done any searching? Formatting an `NSDate` into an `NSString` using `NSDateFormatter` has to be one of the most common questions in this site.

Comment: I don't want to make it to an NSString, I want it to be an NSDate

Comment: But you said you wanted to get the current date in a specific format. And you already know how to get the current date as an `NSDate`. So the only way to get an `NSDate` in a specific format is to format the `NSDate` into an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get current day like format this: dd/MM/yyyy.

You can use this code:

```
NSDate *datecenter = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d, MMMM, YYYY"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:datecenter];
lbldaymonthyear.text = dateString;
```

Comment: This is incorrect. If you want a date in the format "dd/MM/yyyy" then the format specifier needs to be `@"dd/MM/yyyy"`. Do not use `YYYY` for the year.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most succinct way, you can use different NSDateFormatterStyles to change the way the date is displayed later

```
NSString *date = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]
                                                        dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                        timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

NSDateFormatterShortStyle
Specifies a short style, typically numeric only, such as “11/23/37” or “3:30 PM”.

Equal to kCFDateFormatterShortStyle.

More styles here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDateFormatterStyle

Comment: I get a warning saying: "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSDate *' with an expression of type 'NSString *'"

Comment: @Eric Make sure you use `NSString *date =` and not `NSDate *date =`.

Comment: @rmaddy That was the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
NSDate *datecenter = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd, MMMM, YYYY"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:datecenter];
yourlabel.text = dateString;
```